# Get Kubernetes LoadBalancer host name

Tags: kubernetes

I have a couple of load balancers I configure as Kubernetes services, but I need to know what their host names are at runtime so they can be used for my other deployments. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to access the host name variable, and I don't want to have to manually set my endpoints every time my cluster is brought up and down. Is it possible to get this done with my current method?

Example LoadBalancer:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: landing-lb
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    lbtype: landing-lb
  ports:
  - port: 4000
    targetPort: 4000
    name: landing
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: landing-portal-dns
spec:
  containers:
  - name: landing-portal
    image: registry.k8s.io/busybox
    env:
      - name: PORTAL_LANDING
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            fieldPath: status[0].loadBalancer[0].ingress[0].hostname
```

Error: `Error from server (Invalid): error when creating "services/landing-lb.yaml": Pod "landing-portal-dns" is invalid: spec.containers[0].env[0].valueFrom.fieldRef.fieldPath: Invalid value: "status[0].loadBalancer[0].ingress[0].hostname": error converting fieldPath: field label not supported: status[0].loadBalancer[0].ingress[0].hostname`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this sequence is possible as you describe it.

The `valueFrom: { fieldRef: }` syntax you show in the question tries to use the [downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/) to try to inject runtime information into a Pod.  This can only inject data from the current Pod, though, and then only [specific fields](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/downward-api/#available-fields) from it.  You can find out your Pod's name, or the name of the Node that is running it, but you can't find out anything about the Service(s) (if any) that point at the Pod.

There are some ways around this (the [Helm](https://helm.sh) [`lookup`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function) function, for example) but there's also a sequencing problem you run into.  You need to, in order,

1. Create the LoadBalancer-type Service
2. Let a provisioner create the actual load balancer and populate the Service fields
3. Only then create the actual Pods

Standard tools like `kubectl` or `helm` can't perform this "create A, wait for it to be fully set up, then create B" ordering.

If you can write a Kubernetes [operator](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/) then you could implement this sequencing.  What I might do here is create a custom resource that names a Service to watch and a ConfigMap to create.  In your Pod spec, include a non-optional reference to the ConfigMap, but do not define the ConfigMap.  Instead, your controller code watches the Service; when it exists and has a load-balancer name, it creates the ConfigMap (and if it gets deleted, it deletes the ConfigMap).  Since the Pod requires the ConfigMap to be able to be created, this will insert the delay you need.

(You could write similar logic using a shell script and `kubectl` too, but it would be less robust, especially against the entire application being uninstalled and recreated.)

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for the informed answer!